# adding buttons dynamically in android

Tags: android-layout

I'm new to android development and needs help here.I want to create a layout where buttons are added dynamically.In this the no of buttons to be added are decided on the fly.(at run time) i.e depending upon the number return by server i want to add buttons.below is the layout i want to create.Please suggest me suitable solution.I was trying creating this layout with table layout.Thank You

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbrEq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in your array of buttons and initialize your empty layout (i.e. setContentView). Then, create your buttons using the ImageButton constructor and call .addView(btn) from the layout where you want to insert the button. Don't forget to set any layout parameters you need.